# Women kidnapped and dumped on an alien planet with pod-born babies and roaming dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book about human females kidnapped from Earth and dumped on a planet on top of a sacred mountain. One of the ladies wanders off and found an inhabitant of the planet. The planet does not have a lot of females and the babies are born in plant-like pods.

They eventually discovered the sacred mountain is a crashed ship because of the lights coming from the mountain on certain nights. Some of the ladies were eaten by dinosaur creatures.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: I'm at a loss why someone would vote to close this as 'needs details'. I count no less than 9 pieces of relevant info (book/women kidnapped/sacred mountain/finds inhabitant/not very many women/babies born in pods/mountain is crashed ship/lights at night/woman eaten by dinosaur) that in combination almost certainly have to be a unique identifier

Answer (score 13):

[Caveman Alien's Ransom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34858083-caveman-alien-s-ransom) by Calista Skye.

[image: Caveman Alien's Ransom]

> Being abducted by aliens was never on my bucket list!
>
> But I guess the aliens didn't get that memo, because one night I was beamed aboard a UFO. It dumped me and a bunch of other girls on an alien planet!
>
> A jurassic planet where giant, murderous dinosaurs walk around and everything wants to kill me. My only hope of surviving is the first man I met here. His name is Jax'zan, and he's an alien...
>
> And a caveman!
>
> As in, the hottest super-alpha caveman who ever lived. He's big and strong and doesn't talk much, but he's saved my life so many times now that I've lost count. My insides turn to hot mush whenever he fixes his smouldering eyes on me, and the scandalously sexy and unusual features his sensationally muscular body is rocking totally make me forget time and place. There's only one problem: He's holding me for ransom. And he wants to repopulate his woman-less planet. With me...

The plants that grow babies are called *Lifegivers*:

> Then we go to check out the Lifegivers. Sophia described them to me, and these look a lot like those.
>
> They're basically plants, but they also have some animal in them, and probably some fungus stuff, too. They move and look weird, and they can provide a human fetus with everything it needs to grow to birth size.
>
> Ar'ox peels away the layers of green and red leaves until I can see a translucent pod with what is clearly a human fetus inside, suspended in a cloudy liquid.

The mountain does indeed turn out to be a spaceship:

> “Sophia,” she says, and her voice has a strange tremble to it. “If you look at the top of that mountain ... and you squint a little ... doesn't that look like something else?”
>
> The sun is low behind the trees and I shield my eyes with one hand. From this angle, a part of the mountain near the top is rounded and strangely symmetric. Unnaturally so. And it has a sharp edge that seems perfectly circular. There's green vegetation all over it, so I can't see any specific details. But the color is different than the rest of the mountain below, lighter and somehow more even.
>
> My hand flies unbidden to my mouth. I've seen my share of sci-fi movies and then some. I recognize a rocket engine nozzle when I see one. And I'm looking at one right now.
>
> No, two

Found by Googling for [women abducted dinosaur science fiction site:goodreads.com/book/](https://www.google.com/search?q=women%20abducted%20dinosaur%20science%20fiction%20site%3Agoodreads.com%2Fbook%2F). It was third in the list.

Comment: Full marks for resilience, sir.  Having found that as the answer, I suspect I would have let this go unanswered in the hope that the OP found something better to read!

Comment: Wow you guys are awesome